# Port 445 open to Mac but closed to Linux?

Tags: windows-7, mac-osx, windows-firewall

I'm running a Windows 7 Ultimate, and I'm attempting to set up file sharing (SMB). I have a Linux system which can't seem to connect. When running mmap in Linux to scan port 445, I see that the port is filtered (closed). Yet, on my Mac, I can connect to the Windows PC, and Network Utility shows that port 445 is Open.

What is going on? When I turn off the Windows 7 firewall, Linux can connect. I realize that I must change some firewall settings, but how is it that Linux says the port is filtered and Mac says it is open? And to prove that, Mac can connect, and Linux can't.

PS. The Mac is connected via a local switch and the Linux is a server elsewhere.

I am very confused.
Thanks,
Nachum

Answer (score 0):

Ah yes, the firewall defaults to allow connections only from the local subnet.

Comment: Yup, this is a very common head scratcher until you notice that. I do love making security auditors feel stupid when they forget to check this.